# How can I filter x509 certificates by template and expiration date to leave only fresh ones?

Tags: powershell

Another problem with getting users AD certificates. This question is all about filtering output data. We have several certificate templates for different purposes (smartcard, VPN, etc..), and time by time expired certificates still exists in AD. How can I filter list of certificates of each user? I need to leave only **latest certificates of each template**.
AD request example:

```
$user = Get-ADUser username -Properties "Certificates"
$Cert = $user.certificates | foreach {New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2 $_} | select @{n='Fullname';e={$_.subject -replace '^.*?CN=|,.*$'}}, @{n='subject';e={$_.subject -replace '^CN=|^E=|,.*$'}}, Notafter, thumbprint, @{N="Template";E={($_.Extensions | 
            ?{$_.oid.Friendlyname -match "Certificate Template Information|Certificate Template Name"}).Format(0) `
                -replace "(.+)?=(.+)\((.+)?", '$2'}}

$Cert
```

And output is 3 certificates, for example:

```
Fullname   : Full User Name
subject    : subject@domain.com
NotAfter   : 30.05.2019 11:25:45
Thumbprint : hash_1
Template   : temaplate_1

Fullname   : Full User Name
subject    : subject@domain.com
NotAfter   : 02.04.2019 16:56:24
Thumbprint : hash_2
Template   : **template_2**

Fullname   : Full User Name
subject    : subject@domain.com
NotAfter   : 16.05.2018 14:54:22
Thumbprint : hash_3
Template   : **template_2**
```

How can I filter my output to left only latest certificates of each template, eg. hash_1 and hash_2?

Group-object seems nice, but how can I proceed

```
$Cert | Group-Object subject | fl


Name   : subject@domain.com
Count  : 3
Group  : {@{Fullname=Full User Name; subject=subject@domain.com; NotAfter=30.05.2019 11:25:45; Thumbprint=hash_1; Template=temaplate_1}, @{Fullname=Full User Name; subject=subject@domain.com; NotAfter=02.04.2019 16:56:24; Thumbprint=hash_2; Template=template_2}, @{Fullname=Full User Name; subject=subject@domain.com; NotAfter=16.05.2018 14:54:22; Thumbprint=hash_3; Template=template_2}}
Values : {subject@domain.com}
```

I think it is possible to use `Where-Object` somehow to filter the results. Any help?

Comment: What have you tried so far to filter your output? Do you get any error?

Comment: I tried to group by subject or fullname. But then I'm stuck. I'm not strong at filtering data at all. Any way to filter `group-object` result?

Comment: `Where-Object` is the right Cmdlet. Something like that should work `Where-Object {$_.NotAfter -lt (Get-Date)}`

Comment: Sorry for bad question. Edited to clarify. Not "Not Expired" but **Latest** certificates of each certificate template. That's why I'm stuck. There can be more then one alive certificate of `template_1` and `template_2` in same time. I need to get latest ones of `template_1` and `template_2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can group the object by two properties (Subject and Template) with `Group-Object`, sort each group by `NotAfter` and select the first element.

```
$x | Group-Object -Property Subject, Template |
    ForEach-Object {
        $_.Group | 
        Sort-Object -Property NotAfter -Descending | 
        Select-Object -First 1
    }
```

Comment: It does not work because of `Template` property. If I just sort by `NotAfter` and select the first element, I will get one latest certificate of all different templates. I need to sort data like that, but for each type of `Template` property

Comment: I can get all certificates list, then sort it for each template like this `$TemplateOneCerts = $AllCertList | Where-object {$_.Template -eq 'Template_1'}` to get latest certificates... Is there a way to compose all data in one variable later? Smth like  `$AllCertsFiltered = $TemplateOneCerts + $TemplateTwo... etc`

Comment: I updated my answer to your requirements. You can simply group by two properties.

Comment: Oh, didn't know about grouping by several properties. I'll try it.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this, but assuming what you mean is that you want only the certs where `NotAfter` has not past, then this should help:

```
(Get-ADUser username -Properties "Certificates").certificates |
    ForEach-Object {
        New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2 $_
    } | Select-Object @{n='Fullname';e={$_.subject -replace '^.*?CN=|,.*$'}}, 
                      @{n='subject';e={$_.subject -replace '^CN=|^E=|,.*$'}}, 
                      Notafter, 
                      thumbprint,
                      @{N="Template";E={($_.Extensions | 
                            Where-Object {$_.oid.Friendlyname -match "Certificate Template Information|Certificate Template Name"}).Format(0) -replace "(.+)?=(.+)\((.+)?", '$2'}} |
            Where-Object {[DateTime]::Parse($_, (New-Object CultureInfo("en-GB", $false))) -lt [DateTime]::Now}
```

`[DateTime]::Parse()` didn't work directly since it was assuming US culture, so I forced it to a different culture.  You can likely change this to your own culture instead (unless it's `en-US`!).

Comment: Thist doesn't work on my culture settings. But `NotAfter` is half of problem. `Template` is more important, because there can be two or three 'alive' certificates. Eg. `cert1: NotAfter: 15.08.2018 Template: Temp_1` and `cert2: NotAfter: 19.07.2019 Template: Temp_1` because of smartcard loss or some other thigs happened. And `cert3: NotAfter: 05.08.2019 Template: Temp_2` and `cert4: NotAfter: 02.07.2018 Template: Temp_2` I need to filter out `cert2` and `cert3` because it is latest certificates of each template variation, and drop out `cert1` and `cert4` because it is not latest.